# Do OpenID Connect id_token and access_token need to be validated if they are obtained by web server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect, websecurity

I am wondering that in the OpenID Connect **Auth Code Flow**, whether there is still a need to validate the **access_token** and **id_token** given they are obtained by my web server rather than by browser (i.e. using back channel rather than front channel)?

By "auth code flow" I am referring to the flow where browser only receives an "authorization code" from the authorization server (i.e. no access_token, no id_token), and sends the auth code to my web server. My web server can therefore directly talk to the authorization server, presenting the auth code, and exchange it for the access_token and id_token. It looks like I can simply decode the access_token and id_token to get the information I want (mainly just user id etc.)

My understanding of the need for validating the access_token is that because access_token is not encrypted, and **if it is transmitted through an insecure channel**, there is a chance that my web server can get a forged token. Validating the token is basically to verify that the token has not been modified.

But what if the access_token is not transmitted on any insecure channel? In the auth code flow, web server directly retrieves the access_token from the auth server, and the token will never be sent to a browser. Do I still need to validate the token? What are the potential risks if I skip the validation in such flows?

Comment: Related question: [Is ID Token JWT signature actually necessary, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72951617/is-id-token-jwt-signature-actually-necessary-or-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always validate the tokens and apply the well known validation patterns for tokens. Because otherwise you open up your architecture for various vulnerabilities. For example you have the man-in-the-middle issue, if the hacker is intercepting your "private" communication with the token service.

Also most libraries will do the validation automatically for you, so the validation is not a problem.

When you develop identity systems you should follow best practices and the various best current practices, because that is what the users of the system expects from you.

As a client, you use HTTPS to get the public key from the IdentityServer, so you know what you got it from the right server. To add additional security layers, you could also use client side HTTPS certificates, so that the IdentityServer only issues tokens to clients that authenticates using a certificate.

In this way, man-in-the-middle is pretty impossible. However, in data-centers in the backend, you sometimes don't use HTTPS everywhere internally. Often TLS is terminated in a proxy, you can read more about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy)

When you receive an ID-token, you typically create the user session from that. And yes, as the token is sent over the more secure back channel, you could be pretty secure with that. But still many attacks today occurs on the inside, and just to do a good job according to all best practices, you should validate them, both the signature and also the claims inside the token (expire, issuer, audience...).

For the access token, it is important that the API that receives it do validate it according to all best practices, because anyone can send requests with tokens to it.

Also, its fun to learn :-)

ps, this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU9RsE4fcRM) is a good starting point

Comment: What particularly confuses me is that if there is a SSL strip/man-in-the-middle attack, how can I confidently verify my token? To verify the token I will need to get the server's public key - which has to be acquired through another get request. If there is a man in the middle, he can just hijack this communication as well and give me whatever fake key he used to forge the token?

Comment: Thanks. Btw your answer is very valuable no matter what and I will accept it. What I cannot get my head around is that - if using HTTPS to get the public key from the auth server is good enough for the public key to be considered authentic, why the same way is not considered good enough for the tokens?

The access_token and id_token are all retrieved directly from the auth server using HTTPS. If I can trust the public key I should trust these tokens as well?

Comment: updated my answer, how that makes it acceptable, ps, most libraries to the validation for you ,so I wonder why you dont like to validate them and be safe?

Comment: I will, as you said, validate them anyway to follow the convention, but I do want to know what is going on behind the scene rather than following conventions blindly. There are libraries out there indeed that claim to handle all the complexity for me, but I am a bit skeptical about how robust/universally applicable these libraries are, i.e. do they all perform the same set of validations in the same fashion? If so, they must be interchangeable? Then which one should I use?

Comment: There are certified libraries here https://openid.net/developers/libraries/ and depending on the platform that you use, do go for the actively maintained libraries and that have open source code. I do agree that you should look into the packages and learn and see how they work, because libraries do have bugs. see https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/ and https://insomniasec.com/blog/auth0-jwt-validation-bypass