# Is ID Token JWT signature actually necessary, or not?

Tags: openid

In the Authorization Code OpenID workflow, the final step includes the web application ("client") trading an authorization code for an ID token at the authorization server. The ID token is a JWT, see the [OpenID spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation).

What's the purpose of validating the signature in this case? The server/web application communicates with the authentication server over TLS, as such, the purpose of the signature appears somewhat less clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually acknowledged in the OpenID spec:

> If the ID Token is received via direct communication between the Client and the Token Endpoint (which it is in this flow), the TLS server validation MAY be used to validate the issuer in place of checking the token signature. The Client MUST validate the signature of all other ID Tokens according to JWS [JWS] using the algorithm specified in the JWT alg Header Parameter. The Client MUST use the keys provided by the Issuer.

Possibly, one could argue that the custody of authentication keys and TLS keys on the authorization server should be separate and in that case JWT signature validation would make sense.